# How to change style property in angular with if statement

Tags: angular

Below question is in angular 7

```
<header class="stick-top forsticky gradient">
```

Here is my html content in angular

```
current_path = localStorage.getItem("current_path");
```

current path is a variable in my component.

I wants to make if current_path != '/' in component then 
heder will be like this.

```
<header class="stick-top forsticky gradient">
```

else

```
<header class="stick-top forsticky">
```

I wants to remove gradient class from hrader tag if my current_path is '/'

Answer (score 4):

you can use ngClass:

```
<header class="stick-top forsticky" [ngClass]="{'gradient':current_path != '/'}">
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a single class, a good enough alternative to ngClass is

```
<header class="stick-top forsticky" [class.gradient]=" current_path != '/' " >
```

You may prefer this syntax since it is easier to format and prettify in the html templates than js objects that resolve to classes.